# Is there a more elegant way to write this lazy loading pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift, lazy-loading

I've considered null coalescing and if let, nothing seems that great so far, any ideas?

```
var habitResults: [[String:String]]? = resultsFilteredByHabit[habitId]

if habitResults != nil {
    // No action required
}
else {
    habitResults = results.filter({ $0["habitId"] == habitId })
    resultsFilteredByHabit[habitId] = habitResults
}
```

Comment: Does `habitId` never change? Otherwise lazy loading makes no sense.

Comment: @vadian, not in this scope

Comment: Did you consider anything like that:
[link] https://gist.github.com/GienaM/2212f1032718e044af9095d5b58ff51e

Comment: @GienadijMackiewicz Interesting idea to use guard, but seems to increase the complexity that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual lazy loading pattern syntax in Swift is

```
lazy var habitResults : [[String:String]] = {
    return results.filter{ $0["habitId"] == habitId }
}()
```

The closure is executed **once** when the variable is accessed the first time

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks a little more elegant:

```
resultsFilteredByHabit[habitId] = resultsFilteredByHabit[habitId] ?? results.filter({ $0["habitId"] == habitId })
```